# star schema database in sql server

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, dimensions, star-schema, fact-table

I create a test1 database in sql server 2008 r2 and then another test 2 db ..

```
tables
product_info table
Product_id
product_name
unitprice
unitsonorder

user_info table
user_id
user_name
user_pwd
email
city
product_id
```

and in test 2 db i create star schema erd is
[image]

now here i want to select data from test1 db and then execute in test2 db .. like etl.. extract, transform and load...

here is the query

```
create procedure spinsert1
as
insert into user_dimension ( user_name,email)
select USER_NAME,email from test1.dbo.userinfo
```

when i execute this uery data is not inserted in table

so how i done this?

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly you are up to. What does it mean: select data from test1 db and then execute in test2 db?

Comment: means that when i select record from abc table then i want to inset this record in another database abc table

Comment: So where's the problem? Can you post the query you have and explain what's not working and how would you expect it to work?

Comment: user_id is primary key, is it identity column? if not your insert wold give error. only two column values are selected, are other columns having NULL, if not insert will fail

Comment: i also check tick mark null option